# How to Manage data in APC

Tags: php, design-patterns, apc

How to manage different type of data in APC? As APC stores data in key value pair how to store data so that it is possible to sore different type of object?
eg i want to store session data as well as some other object for caching.

Initially i am thinking of to append class name with id to store it as in key and the object as value. I belive there is much better way than that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, APC stores values using a key-value system. If you want to store sessions then each APC key must be unique. Since session keys are already unique it should not be more difficult than prepending something like `sessid_` to the id:

```
$key = 'sessid_'.session_id();
apc_add($key, $value, 3600 * 6);
```

While APC will probably work okay, it may however not be the best storage mechanism. APC's datastore is more geared toward storing commonly used data such as constants, configuration, counters, globally used strings, etc. Further more, when you store stuff in APC the data is serialized and then unserialized every time you read and write to it. Seeing as sessions are usually contained in something like an array or an object this is not quite optimal.

Sessions are fleeting and usually change quite a lot, as needed. The point of caching stuff is that you intend to *read* the data a lot more than you *write* it. If the session data changes often (such as when the user was last active, how often they have logged in or out, etc.) then it defeats the purpose of caching it. In cases like that a database is probably a better fit. And it does not need to be good old MySQL. There are many kinds of databases out there; some are better suited than others.

Comment: apart from session usage suppose i want to store different configuration file as well as cached object (which is pulled from database and used in page rendering). I want something like some object which will manage other cacheObject (apc cache). I forgot the design pattern name. As far i can remember there is something like that.